# Filtering venues with the Foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

I'm building an app where I want to get all restaurants in a given radius from a coordinate with the Foursquare API, but I want certain filters applied. Specifically, I want to filter by:

- if the venue is currently open
- the price range of the venue
- keyword searches defined by the user
- one or more categories returned by the [categories endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories)

My app is focused on restaurants, so I want to unconditionally filter the result to be in the "Food" category (ID #`4d4b7105d754a06374d81259`). The [explore endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) is documented to support filters for `openNow`, `price`, and `query`, but it does not list support for a `categoryId`, which is crucial. It appears to have undocumented support for a `categoryId` filter, but it only allows one ID in this parameter, and the *or more* part is crucial.

The [search endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) is documented to support filtering by one or more `categoryId`s and a `query`, but not `openNow` or `price` like [explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) can filter by. Is it possible to achieve the feature set I want with the Foursquare API without having to do my own data processing?

**UPDATE:** I stumbled across a [search recommendations endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/search/recommendations) that seems to meet my needs. However, the documentation for this endpoint says that it's only available to specific whitelisted partners. If it's not possible to get the feature set I want in the current public set of APIs, how would I go about getting on this whitelist?

Comment: And unfortunately it looks like the search recommendations endpoint page has disappeared with the Docs overhaul.

Comment: I saw that :( Also, their `multi` endpoint isn't in the docs anymore, but it still works if you hit it with a `v` of a date when it was documented (or maybe the current, too. I haven't tested). I was gonna post another question sometime soon about how to batch requests now after the docs update

Comment: Yep, I was going to say the `multi` endpoint would be an option but since it's not in the current docs I'm not sure I'd recommend going that route. You could do multiple async requests to the `explore` endpoint on your end, one request for each category, then combine them into a single promise.